# kube-ui dashboard 503 error caused by cAdvisor

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cadvisor

I'm trying to use kube-ui, but I got a 503 error in dashboard. Looking a solution for it I found that is caused by cAdvisor and it is embedded in kubelets. But, I don't know why this is occurring.
I'm starting my hyperkube kubelet using this command:

```
`docker run --net=host -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v1.0.7 /hyperkube kubelet --api_servers=http://localhost:8080 --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --enable_server --hostname_override=127.0.0.1 --allow-privileged=true --cadvisor-port=4194 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests-multi`
```

And kube-ui:

```
kubectl create -f cluster/addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-rc.yaml
kubectl create -f cluster/addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-svc.yaml
```

I tried too, run a cadvisor container and then the dashboard appeared, but master and slave graphics information are the same. Command line that I used:

```
sudo docker run \
--volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
--volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
--volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
--volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro \
--publish=4194:8080 \
--detach=true \
--name=cadvisor \
google/cadvisor:latest
```

Comment: Are your pods in a Running or Pending status?

Comment: @George running status

Comment: Did you try checking the logs for any error messages? "cluster/kubectl.sh log <podname> [<containername>]"

Comment: @George look what Evandro answered, It is the errors that we found

Comment: After looking at the error message, this issue should be resolved in the 1.1 release. Do you mind trying the latest v1.1 beta release?

Comment: @George I installed v1.1.1 and now dashboard works without cadvisor docker. =] but graphic's informations are the same: Here print: http://imgur.com/QgqFKf0

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on my end. Is it possible to try redeploying the cluster?